# bilinear form of PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $D ⊂ R^m$ be a bounded, open set with smooth boundary $∂D$. Consider the bilinear form
$B_λ[u,v] := \int_D <∇u,∇v>dx + λ \int_D uvdx$ ,   $λ ∈ R$

defined for functions  $ u,v ∈ H^1(D)$.

(a) Prove, using the Riesz representation theorem, that for $λ>0$  and  $f∈L^2(D)$ , there exists a unique weak solution $ u ∈ H^1(D) $ of the problem:
$B_λ[u, v] := <f,v>_{L^2} =\int_Dfvdx, ∀v ∈ H^1(D)$ ------- (1)

(b) Explain via informal arguments that $−∆u + λu = f,   \frac{∂u}{∂ν}|_{∂D} = 0$ ------ (2)

is the partial differential equation associated to the weak formulation in (1), where $ν$ is the outward pointing normal on $∂D$;
The Poincar´e inequality for functions in $H^1_0(D)$ can be extended to $H^1(D)$-functions. Let $D ⊂ R^n$ be a bounded,
connected, open set with smooth boundary from this point on. Then, for some $c > 0$,
$||u − \bar{u}||_{L^2} ≤ c||∇u||_{L^2} $ , $∀u ∈ H^1(D)$ -------(3)

where $\bar{u} =\frac{1}{|D|}\int_Dudx$, the average of $u$ over $D$.

(c) Show that the subspace $H := \{u ∈ H^1(D) | \bar{u} = 0\}$   is closed and thus defines a Hilbert space;

(d) Use the Poincar´e inequality in (3) to give an appropriate equivalent norm on $H$.

(e) Show that (1) has a weak solution for $λ = 0$ if and only if $\int_Dfdx =0$.

(f) Describe the set of all weak solutions for $λ = 0$.

In fact I don't know how can I apply Riesz representation theorem to solve (a). I also didn't understand the question (b). For the question (c), to show that $H$ is closed I take sequence convergence to $\bar{u}$ and show $\bar{u}∈H$ but I think that not true. I think I have a part of solution of question (e) but not complete. So I need help to solve this problem complete, please. Thank you very much.

Comment: What you are asking (I guess this is a problem set from a course) is a standard arguments in weak formulations of PDEs. Maybe just try to read lecture notes available to you carefully. It is not complicated questions.

Comment: You found it uncomplicated, but I tried to solve it and could not. Would you like to help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

(a) The key insight to be able to use the Riesz Representation Theorem is to show that the bilinear form $B_\lambda[u, u]$ defines a scalar product which induces a norm on the Hilbert space $H^1 (D)$. Without presenting the whole proof, you need that your bilinear form is symmetric and linear in the first argument, which is due to the symmetry actually equivalent to prescribing linearity in both arguments (this is why we call it bilinear). These things are trivially shown. Next for a scalar product you need that it is positive definite, i.e., $B_\lambda[u, u] > 0 \: \forall u \in H^1(D): u \neq 0$. This is true if $B_\lambda[u, v]$ is *coercive*, i.e., $$ \exists c > 0 \text{ such that } B_\lambda[u, u] \geq c \Vert u \Vert_{H^1(D)}^2 \: \forall \: u \in H^1(D).$$
Finally, to have that your problem-dependent Hilbert Space is actually a Hilbert Space, you need that it is complete. For this, you require continuity of the bilinear form:
$$ \exists C>0 \text{ such that } B_\lambda[u, v] \leq C \Vert u \Vert_{H^1(D)} \Vert v \Vert_{H^1(D)}$$
Then, $B_\lambda[u,v]$ can be used to define a Hilbert-space $(V, B_\lambda) $ for vectors $u, v \in V$, where $V$ is a vector space. Thus, you can finally apply the Riesz representation theorem since you know that $f \in L^2(D)$ which implies \begin{align}(f, v)_{L^2(D)} \overset{\text{Cauchy-Schwarz}}{\leq} & \Vert f \Vert_{L^2(D)}  \Vert v \Vert_{L^2(D)} \leq \Vert f \Vert_{L^2(D)}  \Vert v \Vert_{H^1(D)} \\
\overset{\text{Coercivity}}{\leq} & \Vert f \Vert_{L^2(D)}  \sqrt{\frac{B_\lambda[v,v]}{c}} \\
\overset{K:= \Vert f \Vert_{L^2(D)},\Vert v \Vert_{B}:= \sqrt{B_\lambda[v,v]} }{=}& \frac{K}{\sqrt{c}} \Vert v \Vert_{B}.
\end{align}
Thus, $(f, v)_{L^2(D)} =:F(v) $ is also in your custom Hilbert Space $(V, B_\lambda)$ a bounded linear functional.
Thus, you can finally apply Riesz:
$$ \exists ! u \in H^1(D) \text{ such that } B_\lambda [u, v] = F(v) \: \forall \: v \in H^1(D)$$

(b) Note that \begin{align} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v = \nabla \cdot (v \nabla u ) - v \Delta u \end{align}
and thus
\begin{align} \int_D  \nabla u \cdot \nabla v \mathrm d x = \int_D \nabla \cdot (v \nabla u ) - v \Delta u  \mathrm d x \end{align}
and via Gauss / Divergence theorem
\begin{align} \int_D \nabla \cdot (v \nabla u ) - v \Delta u  \mathrm d x = &\int_{\partial D} (v \nabla u ) \cdot n \mathrm d s - \int_D v \Delta u  \mathrm d x \\
=& \int_{\partial D} v \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} \mathrm d s - \int_D v \Delta u  \mathrm d x  \\
=& - \int_D v \Delta u  \mathrm d x \end{align}
Thus, your weak form reads
\begin{align} \int_D v (- \Delta u + \lambda u) \mathrm d x &= \int_D f v \mathrm d x \: \forall \: v \in H^1(D) \\ 
\overset{\nabla}{\Rightarrow} v(- \Delta u + \lambda u)&=f v \: \forall \: v \in H^1(D)  \end{align} which implies the point-wise equation.

Comment: Dear Dan, would you like to give me answers for (c),(d),(e) and (f). I am also struggling with them. Thank you very much

Comment: I was able to come up with solutions for (a), (b) since they are sort of standard - the other problems I have not yet done by myself and I unfortunately have right now not the time to do them thoroughly, I am sorry.

Comment: in (a) second line, is the bilinear form $B_λ[u,u]$ or $B_λ[u,v]$ ?

Comment: There it is indeed $B_\lambda [u, \color{red} v ]$. For coercivity, you have the same argument: $ B_\lambda [u, \color{red} u]$.

Comment: Dear Dan, what is $K$ and $||v||_B$ in the last inequality in (a)?

Comment: I defined it over the arrow, basically $K$ is a shortcut for the $L^2$-norm of $f$ which is known to be finite. $\Vert v \Vert_B$ is just a shortcut for the induced norm from the scalar product $B_\lambda[v, v]$.

Comment: This line shows that $K$ is equal product of norm $f$ and norm $v$ and definition of norm $v$ not clear. Would you like to rewrite them more clearly, please?

Comment: There is a comma $,$ in between. Furthermore, I use the "defined through equality with" notation $:=$.